# Real Analysis- Convergence of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x=\left(x_n\right)$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to x. Then prove that the sequence $\alpha X$ converges to $\alpha x$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I started with the finding an $n_1$ that satisfies the definition of convergence $\left|x_{n_1}-x\right|<\frac{ε}{\alpha }$. I am pretty sure this step is itself not in the right direction as $\alpha \left|x\right|\:$ is not always equal to $\left|\alpha x\right|$. Added to that cross multiply alpha would mean me imply that $\alpha >0$ which is not the case here or I might have to approach two different cases.

So how do I make this proof?

Comment: To show $\alpha.x_n$ converges to $\alpha.x$ you need to show that $|\alpha x_n -\alpha x|$ becomes arbitrarily small provided $n$ is large enough. Can you rewrite $|\alpha x_n - \alpha x|$ in some way that expresses it in terms of a quantity you can ensure becomes arbitrarily small for large $n$?

Comment: I have to say there exists an n such that $\left|x_n-x\right|>\frac{ε}{\left|\alpha \right|}$ Then by the property $\left|\alpha \right|\left|x\right|=\left|\alpha x\right|$ I can get to the final statement. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that works, apart from one special value of $\alpha$, which you can handle directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence $X=(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\geq n_0$ we have that: $$|x_n-x|<\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|},\;\; \alpha\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\},$$ as we can make $\epsilon$ as small as we want. Then, multiply both sides by $|\alpha|$ and we get: $$|\alpha||x_n-x|=|\alpha x_n-\alpha x|<\epsilon,$$
Therefore, we can conclude that whenever $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ we have that $(\alpha x_n)\rightarrow \alpha x$.

Comment: For completeness one would normally add a few words about what happens when $\alpha=0$.